# Setting background image in Android for mdpi, ldpi, hdpi

Tags: android, size, screen, android-image

I'm working on setting background image sized 320X480 jpg, for >= android 2.2 versions.

As per my understanding from previous posts related to mdpi,ldpi,hdpi & info from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html , we can use image sized to

ldpi, the recommended size is 240x320.

mdpi, the recommended size is 320x480.

hdpi, the recommended size is 480x800

My question is, will the above mentioned sized images (in jpg format) work (or) should i have to create a single image generated using 9 patch placed in drawable/

and also i'm little confused in using jpg format for background, as i have seen many sample programs referring to png format, is that a standard or can we use any format ?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks - Jitendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screensize doesn't have to be the ones you mentioned - it can be any other. Therefore better use a ninepatch to stretch the image properly. You should still provide different versions of those though, especially if you have parts of the image that don't stretch.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I'm not familiar with creating different versions of nine patch image, does different versions mean different sizes of an image ?

Comment: i mean different versions for different dpis

Comment: so i can use same image size i.e. 320x480 for different dpis, all i have to do is create different stretchable ninepatch images according to my requirement and place them in proper folders ?

Comment: the size should also be based on the ui guidelines. Otherwise the part that's not being stretched will have different sizes on different dpis.

Comment: i think this might be the solution to the problem, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either jpg or png...it does not matter...As for backroung image you can use an image that will have all sizes...just put it in corect folders and you will not have any problems...